# Ao se fazer uma repetição em caso de não haver resposta, alteração nenhuma esta sendo realizada! pq?

Tags: python, python-3.x

É um código simples, mas com base no que vi e andei estudando sobre estrutura de repetição aqui mesmo, cheguei a um modo de faze-lo, porém estou lidando com o seguinte problema: o valor não está sendo acrescido após a opção dada pelo programa estar sendo realizada! sempre me dando como retorno o valor de 0 (zero)!.

segue:

```
valor = int(input('Valor Solicitado: '))
valor1 = int(0)

while True:
    parcelax = input('Qual formato de parcelamento?  \n 1) Á Vista \n 2) 12x  \n 3) 30x \n 4) 60x  \n' )
    if parcelax not in {'1','2','3','4'}:
        print('Digito incorreto!')
        continue
    if parcelax == 1:
        valor1 = 20
    break
print('Olha: {}'.format(valor1))
```

Comment: Vale comentar que `0` já é um valor inteiro, então fazer `int(0)` é redundância. Pode fazer apenas `valor1 = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

É que o método `input` retorna uma `string`.

Você estava testando `if parcelax == 1:` como se `parcelax`  fosse um inteiro.

Opção 1: Então ou você muda para `if parcelax == '1':` testar o valor como string.

Opção 2: Você converte `parcelax` para inteiro desta forma `if int(parcelax) == 1:`

Segue a solução com a opção 1:

```
valor = int(input('Valor Solicitado: '))
valor1 = int(0)

while True:
    parcelax = input('Qual formato de parcelamento?\n 1) Á Vista \n 2) 12x  \n 3) 30x \n 4) 60x  \n' )
    if parcelax not in {'1','2','3','4'}:
        print('Digito incorreto!')
        continue
    if parcelax == '1':
        valor1 = 20
    break
print('Olha: {}'.format(valor1))
```